# Mlxtend Apriori giving error with Sparse DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, sparse-matrix, apriori, mlxtend

Issue with using sparse data frame with mlxtend apriori.

I am running python 2.7 in anaconda and have installed mlxtend. Based on the latest version of mlxtend, the aprioir class supports sparse dataframe as its input. I have over 500k products that I want to run a market basket analysis on. I am trying to create a onehot encoded sparse dataframe using a small dataset to test but I am running into df.to_coo() issue on the sparse data frame inside the mlextend apriori function.

Please find the code, the input data file and the errors I get here -

https://github.com/nshahHome/pycode

Click on the view code to see the files.

code =  code2.py
input data file=  mbatest.txt
errors = code2-error.html (you may need to download this file and open it in a browser)

I expect the code to not throw errors and try to create frequent_itemsets. The set could be empy if there are no sets > min_support.

Answer (score 0):

This question is now closed as it has been accepted as an enhancement needed by the developer.

https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend/issues/501